Cannot login to Joomla website's backend
I cannot login to my website's administrator panel even after following all the methods mentioned in https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F.
Please help me solve this problem.
Joomla version: 4.3.4.

Problem solved. When I tried the database method mentioned in https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F, I didn't set the password field function to MD5.
See https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_reset_my_joomla_administrator_password/ for more details.
Thank you.

Thanks for explaining the solution that worked for you. Don't forget to accept your answer to show this question has been resolved.

If you are on CPanel and you installed the Joomla using Softaculous, you can edit the installation and put in a new admin username and password there (in softaculous under all installations). That usually works.

I am on DirectAdmin and I installed Joomla manally. Do you know any other method ? Thanks in advance.
